# Symfony Vue JS import App not working without file type

Tags: symfony, vue.js, phpstorm

I tried importing my App. vue file inside app.js like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App';

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: h => h(App)
});
```

My App.vue file:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h2>My Application</h2>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {

        }
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

This doesnt work an gives me this error:
"export 'default' (imported as 'App') was not found in './App'

However, if I add `.vue` inside my import it suddenly works just fine. In other tutorials I found for Symfony and vue it works fine without having to add .vue. Any reason as to why it's not working for me?

Comment: I'd guess that `./App` is matching something other than `App.vue`. Possibly it's matching `app.js` due to Windows case-insensitivity?

Comment: if the extension is missing, same-named `.js` files will have a priority over .vue files. Try Ctrl+clicking on `'./App'` - what file are you taken to?